# CSS/HSS Parser in Treetop and Nested Stylesheet Rules

Tags: ruby, treetop

I'm new to Treetop and attempting to write a CSS/HSS parser. HSS augments the basic functionality of CSS with nested styles, variables and a kind of mixin functionality.

I'm pretty close - the parser can handle CSS - but I fall down when it comes to implementing a style *within* a style. e.g:

```
#rule #one {
  #two {
    color: red;
  }
  color: blue;
}
```

I've taken two shots at it, one which handles whitespace and one which doesn't. I can't quite get either to work. The treetop documentation is a little sparse and I really feel like I'm missing something fundamental. Hopefully someone can set me straight.

A:

```
 grammar Stylesheet

      rule stylesheet
        space* style*
      end

      rule style
        selectors space* '{' space* properties? space* '}' space*
      end

      rule properties
        property space* (';' space* property)* ';'?
      end

      rule property
        property_name space* [:] space* property_value
      end

      rule property_name
        [^:;}]+
      end

      rule property_value
        [^:;}]+
      end

      rule space
        [\t ]
      end

      rule selectors
        selector space* ([,] space* selector)*
      end

      rule selector
        element (space+ ![{] element)*
      end

      rule element
        class / id
      end

      rule id
        [#] [a-zA-Z-]+
      end

      rule class
       [.] [a-zA-Z-]+
      end
end
```

B:

```
grammar Stylesheet

  rule stylesheet
   style*
  end

  rule style
    selectors closure
  end

  rule closure
    '{' ( style / property )* '}'
  end

  rule property
    property_name ':' property_value ';'
  end

  rule property_name
    [^:}]+
    <PropertyNode>
  end

  rule property_value
    [^;]+
    <PropertyNode>
  end

  rule selectors
    selector ( !closure ',' selector )*
    <SelectorNode>
  end

  rule selector
    element ( space+ !closure element )*
    <SelectorNode>
  end

  rule element
    class / id
  end

  rule id
    ('#' [a-zA-Z]+)
  end

  rule class
    ('.' [a-zA-Z]+)
  end

  rule space
    [\t ]
  end

end
```

Harness Code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'treetop'

class PropertyNode < Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode
  def value
    "property:(#{text_value})"
  end
end

class SelectorNode < Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode
  def value
    "--> #{text_value}"
  end
end

Treetop.load('css')

parser = StylesheetParser.new
parser.consume_all_input = false

string = <<EOS
#hello-there .my-friend {
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:12px;
}
.my-friend, #is-cool {
  font: 12px Verdana;
  #he .likes-jam, #very-much {asaads:there;}
  hello: there;
}
EOS

root_node = parser.parse(string)

def print_node(node, output = [])
  output << node.value if node.respond_to?(:value)
  node.elements.each {|element| print_node(element, output)} if node.elements
  output
end

puts print_node(root_node).join("\n") if root_node

#puts parser.methods.sort.join(',')
puts parser.input
puts string[0...parser.failure_index] + '<--'
puts parser.failure_reason
puts parser.terminal_failures
```

Comment: Can you post the error/output you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're running into [left recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) problems?  If so, keep in mind that TreeTop produces [recursive descent parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), and as such, you can't really use left recursion in your grammar.  (One of the main reasons I still prefer ocamlyacc/ocamllex over TreeTop despite its very sexy appearance.)  This means you need to convert from left recursive forms to right recursion.  Since you undoubtedly own the [Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) (right?), I'll direct you to sections 4.3.3, 4.3.4, and 4.4.1 which cover the issue.  As is typical, it's hard-to-understand, but parsers didn't get their reputation for nothing.  There's also a nice [left recursion elimination tutorial](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Left-Recursion+Removal) that the ANTLR guys put up on the subject.  It's somewhat ANTLR/ANTLRworks specific, but it's slightly easier to understand than what's found in the Dragon Book.  This is one of those things that just doesn't ever make a whole lot of sense to anyone who hasn't done it at least a few times before.

Also, minor comment, if you're going to use TreeTop, I recommend doing this instead:

```
def ws
  [\t ]*
end
```

You're not likely to ever need to match a single whitespace character, plus almost every grammar rule is going to need it, so it makes sense to name it something very short.  Incidentally, there **are** advantages to a separate lexing step.  This is one of them.

Comment: Ah, right! I assumed TreeTop would be able to handle left recursion and I was just missing something in the documentation. Thanks very much for taking the time to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone beat me to it:

http://lesscss.org/

Although I notice that they use regular expressions and an eval() to parse the input file rather than a parser.

Edit: Now they use TreeTop! It's like someone did all the hard work for me.